# Using i18n with Moment on Parse.com

Tags: javascript, internationalization, parse-platform, momentjs

How can I use i18n translations with Moment.js on Parse.com?

```
var moment = require('moment');
moment.lang('sv');
```

I get this error:

```
The error was Error: Module ./lang/sv not found
```

Where do I put the module? Can I inject it into moment.js with require?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the default `moment.js` library provided by Parse, you can use your custom library.

Download [moment-with-langs](http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-langs.js) and place it under your `cloud` folder in your Cloudcode.
Then you can include this in your main.js by calling

```
var moment = require('cloud/moment-with-langs.js');
```